# Execute python script through PHP

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

I am typing this post after trying multiple ways of resolving permission issue with python, apache and php.
What I am trying is to copy a file from one directory to another. I have set all the directory owner as www-data and chmod to 777
When I run the python script under user www-data it runs fine and copies the file, however with PHP calls the python script it only seems it copies the file however doesn't copy the content. So the file essentially is blank.

python file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
subprocess.call([ 'cp','sched2','/folder/test'])
```

PHP code

```
exec("/folder/test.py");
```

Folder permissions:

- /folder and /folder/test is owned by www-data with mode 777

File permissions:

- test.py and sched2 is owned by www-data and mode 777

PHP file is in /var/www

Comment: Did you try providing sched2 also with full path? Remember that PHPs current working directory may point somewhere else and python would copy only a nonexistent file. You could also chdir in PHP to the directory which contains sched2.

Comment: Thanks Syck, this worked after full path to sched2